# SetForegroundWindow() doesn't work for non main windows

Tags: c#, windows

Let's say I have 2 MS WORD windows, first one is on the left side of the screen, the other one on the right side. So they are both visible. One of them is the main process and the other one is an instance of the main. When I open another unrelated window and maximize it, MS WORD windows are both on background. In that position, when I use SetForegroundWindow() function for both of the MS WORD windows in a for loop (by giving to the function the handles of two windows), it only brings the main window of MS WORD windows to the front, but I want both of them to come to the front. Thank you.

Comment: This can't be done. Only one window can be set as foreground window in the same time. You can't have 2 active windows.

Comment: I don't want 2 active windows, I just want 2 visible windows next to each other.

Comment: Just call SetForegroundWindow on both windows.  Only the last one will of course be truly in the foreground, but if they are side-by-side then that doesn't matter.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing, but only 1 window comes to the front, it's probably because SetForegroundWindow() function does not work for more than 1 window that belong to 1 process. It just works for the main window.

Comment: Have a look at BringWindowToTop or SetWindowPos instead, both from user32.dll.

Comment: Read the documentation for SetForegroundWindow.  The Remarks detail the likely reason *why* this isn't working for you.  It's documented *not to work* the way you're using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! First you need to call SetForegroundWindow() function and after that call SetWindowPos() function with these parameters:

```
SetForegroundWindow(handle);
SetWindowPos(handle, (IntPtr)HWND_TOP, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
```

Thanks all!